# How can you prove n= $6k +2$ when the $x^2$ and $x^3$ coefficient of $(2k +x)^n$ is the same?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I've tried working out the coefficients for each

$$\binom{n}{2}(2k)^{n-2}=\binom{n}{3}(2k)^{n-3}$$

But I'm not sure if that's helpful in any way? And I don't know what to do next?

Comment: Did you mean (2x+n)^n in the title?

Comment: No the question says k

Comment: But then how can there be an x^2 and x^3 coefficient in the expansion if there is no x?

Comment: oh sorry its meant to be 2k + x. ill change it now sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand the binomials and cancel the $2k$'s:
$$\frac{n(n-1)}2(2k)=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}6$$
We can cancel $n(n-1)$ too, and multiply by $6$:
$$3(2k)=n-2$$
$$n=6k+2$$

Answer (score 2):

Use the formula ${n\choose 2}={n(n-1)\over 2}$ and ${n\choose 3}={n(n-1)(n-2)\over 6}$.

Plug into your result you get $${n(n-1)\over 2}\times {(2k)}^{n-2}={n(n-1)(n-2)\over 6}\times{(2k)}^{n-3}$$

Cancel out both side you get $6k=n-2$

Answer (score 2):

Yes you're on the right track, we just need to simplify the equation.

First divide out by $(2k)^{n-3}$ and use the formula for binomial coefficients to get
$$ \frac12 n(n-1) \times 2k = \frac16 n(n-1)(n-2)$$
$$ k = \frac16 (n-2)$$
$$ n = 6k+2$$